# iOS swift multithreading with dispatch global queue blocks main thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, user-interface, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to build an app that downloads some certain images in the background with using grand central dispatch. However even if I use the global queue and dispatch priority background to get a different thread and download the image there it blocks the main thread.All in one class DownloadRequestViewController. In this class I am instantiating code from alertcontroller action.
Here it is :

```
        controller = UIAlertController(title: "Seçenekler", message: "Ne yapmak İstersiniz?", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
        let actionDownload = UIAlertAction(title: "Bölümü İndir", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {(paramAction : UIAlertAction!) in
            var mbProHud : MBProgressHUD!
            var viewToDisplay : UIWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.last as! UIWindow
            mbProHud = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(viewToDisplay, animated: true)
            mbProHud.customView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "37x-Checkmark.png"))
            mbProHud.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.CustomView
            mbProHud.dimBackground = true
            mbProHud.labelText = "İndirme Başlatıldı!"
            mbProHud.hide(true, afterDelay: 2)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {
                var selectedChapters : [String] = [self.currentChapter]
                var mangaNameArray = [self.obtainedManga.name]
                let notification = NSNotification(name: "downloadListNotification", object: self, userInfo: ["downloadList" : selectedChapters, "mangaName" : mangaNameArray])
                self.downloadChapter(notification)
                //NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification(notification)
            })

        })
        controller!.addAction(actionDownload)
```

And here is the signature of download chapter method:

```
func downloadChapter(notification : NSNotification){}
```

I don't think that what is inside of the download chapter would matter.
Please any help would be appreciated, thanks...